# Extract title inside html <script> using BeautifulSoup in python3

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have a html page and i want to extract the title which is inside  tag and inside object _BFD.BFD_INFO. i have accessed all the data inside  but it has a lot of other data  like links etc and now i don't know how to access that title which i want to extract. Kindly help me with it. 
the code so far i have written is

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib3.request
import requests

sauce= 
requests.get('https://www.meishij.net/zuofa/huaguluobodunpaigutang.html')
print(sauce.status_code)
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce.content,'html.parser')
#print(soup.find_all("script", type="text/javascript")[9])
print(soup.find("script",type="text/javascript")[9])
```

and this is the html

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
_czc.push(﻿﻿['_trackEvent','pc','pc_news']);
_czc.push(﻿﻿['_trackEvent','pc','pc_news_class_6']);
window["_BFD"] = window["_BFD"] || {};
_BFD.BFD_INFO = {
"title" :"花菇萝卜炖排骨汤",
</script>
```

Comment: Is the title in this tag`<a id="tongji_title" title="花菇萝卜炖排骨汤的做法" href="https://www.meishij.net/zuofa/huaguluobodunpaigutang.html">花菇萝卜炖排骨汤</a>`  similar to title that you are trying to print

Comment: no , the title is inside <script> like this  <script type="text/javascript">
_czc.push(['_trackEvent','pc','pc_news']);
_czc.push(['_trackEvent','pc','pc_news_class_6']);
window["_BFD"] = window["_BFD"] || {};
_BFD.BFD_INFO = {
"title" :"花菇萝卜炖排骨汤",
"pic" :"http://s1.st.meishij.net/r/216/197/6174466/a6174466_152117574296827.jpg",
"id" :"1883528",
"url" :"https://www.meishij.net/zuofa/huaguluobodunpaigutang.html",
"category" :[["热菜","https://www.meishij.net/chufang/diy/recaipu/"]</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not that good at regex which can be used to find the 'title' in a single line. I guess below code should work.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.meishij.net/zuofa/huaguluobodunpaigutang.html'
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
})

Link = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup =BeautifulSoup(Link.content,"lxml")
scripts = soup.find_all("script")
for script in scripts:
    if "_BFD.BFD_INFO" in script.text:
        text = script.text
        m_text = text.split('=')
        m_text = m_text[2].split(":")
        m_text = m_text[1].split(',')
        encoded = m_text[0].encode('utf-8')
        print(encoded.decode('utf-8'))
```

Update for fetching pic:

```
for script in scripts:
    text = script.text
    m_text = text.split(',')
    for n in m_text:
        if 'pic'  in n:
            print(n)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\siva\Desktop>python test.py

"pic" :"http://s1.st.meishij.net/r/216/197/6174466/a6174466_152117574296827.jpg"
```

Update 2:

```
for script in scripts:
text = script.text
m_text = text.split('_BFD.BFD_INFO')
for t in m_text:
    if "title" in t:
        print(t.split(","))
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\SSubra02\Desktop>python test.py
[' = {\r\n"title" :"????????"', '\r\n"pic" :"http://s1.st.meishij.net/r/216/197/
6174466/a6174466_152117574296827.jpg"', '\r\n"id" :"1883528"', '\r\n"url" :"http
s://www.meishij.net/zuofa/huaguluobodunpaigutang.html"', '\r\n"category" :[["??"
', '"https://www.meishij.net/chufang/diy/recaipu/"]', '["??"', '"https://www.mei
shij.net/chufang/diy/tangbaocaipu/"]', '["???"', '"https://www.meishij.net/chufa
ng/diy/jiangchangcaipu/"]', '["??"', '"https://www.meishij.net/chufang/diy/wucan
/"]', '["??"', '"https://www.meishij.net/chufang/diy/wancan/"]]', '\r\n"tag" :["
??"', '"??"', '"??"', '"????"', '"????"', '"????"]', '\r\n"author":"????"', '\r\
n"pinglun":"3"', '\r\n"renqi":"4868"', '\r\n"step":"7?"', '\r\n"gongyi":"?"', '\
r\n"nandu":"????"', '\r\n"renshu":"4??"', '\r\n"kouwei":"???"', '\r\n"zbshijian"
:"10??"', '\r\n"prshijian":"<90??"', '\r\n"page_type" :"detail"\r\n};window["_BF
D"] = window["_BFD"] || {};_BFD.client_id = "Cmeishijie";_BFD.script = document.
createElement("script");_BFD.script.type = "text/javascript";_BFD.script.async =
 true;_BFD.script.charset = "utf-8";_BFD.script.src =((\'https:\' == document.lo
cation.protocol?\'https://ssl-static1\':\'http://static1\')+\'.baifendian.com/se
rvice/meishijie/meishijie.js\');']
```

Let me know if you are facing any issues.

Comment: it worked. thanks a lot. i just edit this line scripts = soup.find_all("script")

Comment: @Tehseen Yes, thats a better way to do it. I will update it in my code.

Comment: yeah. what if i want to access another element in "_BFD.BFD_INFO"? like in the html i have "pic" and "url"?

Comment: @Tehseen You can check the updated code for fetching the pic

Comment: Thanks @Siva .. you really helped me a lot. i am new to these things. maybe i will ask for help again if i face any issues .

Comment: hey @Siva.. i  want to extract values of more than one elements. the above code prints just "pic", i have about 8 elements like "pinglun":"3","renqi":"4868","step":"7步" etc and i want to extract it's values. can you please help me?

Comment: i did it like this but i think it's not a better way to do it. category=['author', 'pinglun', 'renqi', 'step', 'gongyi', 'nandu', 'renshu', 'kouwei', 'zbshijian', 'prshijian']
for script in scripts:
    text=script.text
    m_text=text.split(',')
    for  n in m_text:
        if category[a] in n:
            print(n)
            a += 1
            if a==9:
             break  ,,, is there any better way to do it?

Comment: @Tehseen Have a look at update 2, its the basic idea from which you can split using `,` and parse the necessary values.